# Data for vehicle speed and altitude at Nürburgring

Tags: data-request, geospatial

Are there any sources of data for driving at [Nürburgring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N%C3%BCrburgring). I would like to get location data (like GPS data) including altitude and vehicle speed during a high speed lap.

Comment: "Telemtry" was in your title, which means "remote sensing". I think for this data, since you don't need real-time, then actually a GPS logger on a vehicle would work the same. That's why I took telemetry out of the title.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Open Street Maps](http://osm.org) has a community portal to upload GPS "traces". These are then publicly accessible.

```
http://www.openstreetmap.org/traces/tag/Nürburgring
```

There isn't a ton of tracks available, but you can try to find other tracks in the region that aren't tagged 'Nürburgring'.

[image]